# Driving chrome to measure page load time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, automation, page-load-time

I have a bunch of URLs and I am trying to see what is the page load time (PLT) for those URLs in chrome on Windows. Now there are many ways to do this - but what I want is to automate the process so that chrome can read from somewhere the URLs I want to measure the PLT for and output the results somewhere, may be in another file.

Is there any tool I can make use of here? Or perhaps write a plugin that can read from a file when I start chrome and do this job for me? I am not sure how simple or complicated this can get, since I have no experience in this.

One way I can think of is to add a plugin that can measure the PLT in chrome, write a batch file which contains commands to invoke chrome and open the URLs in separate tabs. However, with this I still have to manually look at the PLT and record them, and I wish to automate this too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to doing this when a user opens a page in Chrome? In other words, an extension that sits in the background and measures the page load of all pages the user browses to. If so, I can answer this question with a recommendation.

Comment: Yes, an extension that can sit in the browser and report PLT for all the pages loaded by the chrome browser would be just what I need.
 But I need the extension to put the data into a file or database perhaps so that I don't have to look at plugin every time to see what the PLT was.

Comment: Chrome doesn't technically allow you to access the local file system, but you might be able to do it with this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html

Answer (score 1):

""Chrome doesn't technically allow you to access the local file system, but you might be able to do it with this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html.

Another approach is to send the data to another web location via an API. The Google Drive API comes to mind: https://developers.google.com/drive.

You may already be aware that analyzation of the pages can be done via a content script. Simply inject the JavaScript code or libraries you need into pages the user opens, via the manifest file, something like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js" : [
            "some_content_script.js"
        ]
    }
],
```

You'll also need to add "all_urls" to the permissions section of the manifest file.

The load time calculation could simply be accomplished with a timer starting the beginning of the page load (as soon as the script is injected), and ending on "document.onload".

Sounds like a pretty useful extension to be honest!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could approach this

1. Use WebPageTest - either get an API key for the public instance, or install your own private instance (http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/09/18/how-to-create-an-all-in-one-webpagetest-private-instance/)
2. Drive Chrome via it's remote debug API - Andrea provides an example of how to use the API to generate HAR files, but your case would be simpler - https://github.com/andydavies/chrome-har-capturer
3. You could also probably hack this Chrome extension to post the times to a remote site - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-load-time/fploionmjgeclbkemipmkogoaohcdbig via a background window

Comment: Thanks. Let me try those options out and see what fits me best.